# Android, org.json.JSONException: No value for

Tags: android, json

I am getting following json from webservice

```
"alert": { 
    "long_msg": "Thank you for downloading PHARMAPLUS APP, if you found our APP helpful please rate us five star on play store", 
    "short_msg": "Welcome to PHARMAPLUS", 
    "title": "Thank you" 
 }
```

and my code is

```
 if (json.has("alert")) {
     String alert = json.getString("alert");
     String _title = json.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.TITLE);
     String _shortMsg = json.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.SHORT_MSG);
     String _longMsg = json.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.LONG_MSG);
```

Constants are defined like below

```
 public static final String TITLE = "title";
 public static final String SHORT_MSG = "short_msg";
 public static final String LONG_MSG = "long_msg";
```

getting error like below

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for title
```

Comment: why `String alert = json.getString("alert");`?

Comment: Well, the JSON doesn't have a value for "title". The object at the key of "alert" does.

Answer (score 3):

As per the `JSON`

```
"alert": { 
   "long_msg": "Thank you for downloading PHARMAPLUS APP, if you found our APP helpful please rate us five star on play store", 
   "short_msg": "Welcome to PHARMAPLUS", 
   "title": "Thank you" 
 }
```

Here alert is a `JSONObject`. And the values `title`, `long_msg`, `short_msg` are inside `alert`

So, you need to modify this part of code

```
if (json.has("alert")) {
     String alert = json.getString("alert");
     String _title = json.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.TITLE);
     String _shortMsg = json.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.SHORT_MSG);
     String _longMsg = json.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.LONG_MSG);
```

into

```
if (json.has("alert")) {
     JSONObject alert = json.getJSONObject("alert");
     String _title = alert.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.TITLE);
     String _shortMsg = alert.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.SHORT_MSG);
     String _longMsg = alert.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.LONG_MSG);
```

Answer (score 0):

Geet the JSON under alert first and then under that reference the other string values

```
JSONObject alert=json.getJSONObject("alert");;
String _title = alert.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to over come from these problem than you have to make check that the json or string exit in the response or not just like

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(respons);///Here response is your response

if(jsonObject.has("alert"))
{
 JSONObject alert = json.getJSONObject("alert");

 if(alert.has("long_msg"))
 {
  String _longMsg = alert.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.LONG_MSG);
 }

if(alert.has("short_msg"))
 {
  String _shortMsg = alert.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.SHORT_MSG);
 }

if(alert.has("title"))
 {
  String _title = alert.getString(Constansts.PARSE.NOTIFICATION.TITLE);
 }
}
```

It will never throw the exception....which are you getting now